# Can't open election message in 'view all messages' mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, moderator-election, global-inbox

I see a notice for the current election cycle when I mouse over my inbox. But when I view all my messages, it doesn't show up as a proper message that I can click & read. Is this a bug?

Mouse over view - the election message has a summary & I can click to read the full message:

[image]

View all messages view - notice that the election message has no visible summary or link.

[image]

Comment: There is a link; it just has zero-width so it's a bit of a bother to click.

Comment: I don't know where to look at. A hand-drawn red circle would be helpful.

Comment: And an arrow pointing at the circle please. thanks.

Comment: @L_Church added an arrow pointing to the circle

Comment: im only seeing this weird stretched square... :/ (don't comply with this one please imma be in troubles)

Comment: @Pac0 correction, added a red dotted rectangle

Comment: @L_Church yes, the red dotted rectangle is where the message summary should be - the error is that the content in that location is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed.

Inbox item summaries are somewhat special.  For things like comments, we can just serve up the start of the comment.  For elections, on the other hand, we serve up some predetermined text localized for the site you're viewing it on.  So instead of just calling `item.Summary` when you want the summary, you have to call `item.GetLocalizedSummary()`.  It would be nice if we couldn't see `item.Summary`, or if we got a warning for using the wrong one, but we don't. Data models and such, idk.

So, what happened? We got rid of a private API that served up a structure like `{ Summary = item.GetLocalizedSummary() }` and replaced it with a direct reference to `item`.  Since `item.Summary` exists, the code compiled and didn't get updated to point to the correct method.

Comment: The link `href` was valid, but the link couldn't be clicked because it had 0 width.  How about setting a min width via CSS as a fallback for next time?